# Why it's complex to get the applicationContext of a springboot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am not a native English speaker...there maybe some errors in expression, please forgive me..

```java
//import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

//in a @Component class
@Autowired
private static ApplicationContext context
```

I hope that the above code can work, the field variable `context` can get the applicationcontext of the springboot application.. but actually it doesn't work.

I have searched for some means to realize this aim, but I think them complex, for example ,implementing `ApplicationContextAware`...

Please think of factory pattern. Some of the instances which the factory class may return have field variable which need `@Autowired`, so they have to be managed by Spring, and the factory has to `return applicationContext.getBean(...)`, can't use `return new ...` or `return Class.forName(...)`....

I think the factory pattern should be used widely, which I want use to prove that it is meaningful to get the the instance of ApplicationContext of a spring-boot application simply just like the top code...And why it's still complex now?

Thanks.

Comment: why you need this field to be static? if that doesn't want remove static modifier and check

Comment: You should almost never need to do this in the first place. Please explain what you're needing to do that isn't accomplished with an `@Bean` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of Spring as a factory that can create objects for you. These objects are called 'Beans' in spring world.

So, usually the beans do not have an access to the factory that has created them.

For example, think about the factory that produces "cars" like Toyota of Ford.
In terms of OOP, you can "buy" or "drive" the car (an instance of the class Car), but that factory creates these instance (does `new Car`). Since the actual car is managed by spring, its a bean. Now if you describe the car as a class in Java, its not reasonable to have something like this, right?

```
@Component
public class Car {

   ... 
   private CarFactory carFactory;
}
```

So Spring already "hides" the factory for you and you have a class Car "clean" of the boilerplate.

Now, as for the application context itself. It is actually that factory - and as our colleagues have already stated, you shouldn't really use the application context reference in your beans.

If you really need it, you can inject the application context but then it should not be static, and in general its better to access it from the `@Configuration` classes that are supposed to provide the way to create beans in more flexible ways.